# the best way to calculate the position of a number in prime list?

Tags: python, math

for example

```
f(2)->1
f(3)->2
f(4)->-1 //4 is not a prime
f(5)->3
...
```

generally ,make a prime generator and count before it reach x

```
def f(x):
    p = primeGenerator()
    count=1
    while True:
        y = next(p)
        if y>x:
            return -1
        elif y==x:
            return count
        else:
            count+=1
```

wasn't it too slow?though i can cache the list for next call,if i guarantee the input MUST be a prime,so don't have to test if the input number is a prime, is there a faster formula to get the answer?

Comment: Application of the Prime Number Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) might offer something.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - so long as an estimate is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method depends on what inputs you get, and whether the function will be called many times or just once or a few times.

If it will be called often, and all inputs you are going to receive are small, not larger than 10<sup>7</sup> say, the best method is to create a lookup table in advance, and just look up the input.

If it will not be called often, and all inputs are small, just generating the primes not exceeding the input and counting them is certainly good enough. It might be an enhancement to remember what you already have for the next call, so that when the first argument is 19394489, and the next is 20889937, you don't need to start from 0 again, but only need to find the primes between them. But whether the extra storage is worth to be had depends on the arguments passed.

If it will be called often and the arguments are not too large, not exceeding 10<sup>13</sup> say, the best method is to precompute the values of `π(n)` for some select values of `n`, and for each argument look up the value for the next smaller precomputed point, and then generate and count the primes between that point and the target value (or if the target is closer to the next larger precomputed point, count the primes between the target and that).

If you calculate e.g. `π(n)` for all multiples of 10<sup>7</sup> not exceeding 10<sup>13</sup>, you get a lookup table with one million entries, that's not very taxing on the memory nowadays, and never need to sieve a range larger than five million, which doesn't take long.

You could also have the lookup table as a file or database on disk, which would allow much shorter intervals between the precomputed points. That would also eliminate the time for reading in the precomputed table on startup, but the lookup would now involve an access to the file system, which takes much longer than a memory read. What would be the best strategy depends on the expected inputs and the system it's run on.

Computing the lookup table will however take rather long if the upper limit isn't small, but that's a one-time cost.

If the expected inputs are larger, up to 10<sup>16</sup> say, and you're not willing to spend the time necessary for precomputing a lookup table for that range, your best bet is to implement one of the better algorithms for the prime counting function, [Meissel's method as refined by Lehmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_.CF.80.28x.29) is relatively easy to implement (not so easy that I'll give an example implementation here, though, but [here's a Haskell implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/arithmoi/0.4.0.3/doc/html/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Counting.html#v%3aprimeCount) that might help). Better, but more complicated is the method as improved by [Miller et al](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf).

Beyond that, you'd need to research the current state-of-the-art, and probably should use a lower-level language than Python.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check all preceding candidates for primality. There are no shortcuts. As you say, you can cache the result of a prior calculation and start from there, but that's really the best you can do.

Comment: There certainly *are* shortcuts, else we wouldn't know that (for example) 999999999999999999999743 is the 18435599767349200867866th prime.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function for some algorithms.

Comment: No, they're not approximations.  They're exact values for the prime counting function.  Did you follow the link?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Exactly which formula do you refer to? There are many. I'm looking for one with a closed form that I can implement in finite time on a computer.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Which formula in that paper? One that I can code up in Python please.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Legendre's formula? The infinite sum? Sure you can implement that but it's going to take  forever to run.

Comment: @MarkDickinson What would be useful from your would be a clear exposition of an practical algorithm to evaluate the prime counting function. Unless you can point to such a thing, your comments are distracting and unhelpful.